# Prebid.js gulp build failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, prebid.js

I followed the steps from Prebid.js, cleaned and installed node modules, but Module build failed:

```
Type Error: Can not read property 'map' and 'url' undefined.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: ..and what is the stack trace? Where is this exception occurring?

Comment: Please make sure you are using node version > 6.  If you are still having trouble you need to post your environment details.